# Sysparam error with piranha CMS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, nuget, piranha-cms

I've added a piranha CMS template to a MVC empty application from nuget, but when run the first time I get a "Invalid object name sysparam" exception.

I've create a database named piranha-db without tables.
I'm using MVC5.
I've changed my web config following the getting started rules.

Comment: If you go to /manager are you prompted with the login page for the manager or the installation page? and if you take a look in the database, has the tables been created?

Comment: First of all, automapper doesn`t seems to have a correct dependency in nuget package.was missing. I could get to work when I disable breaks on exceptions. Run first time and create tables but when browse root url I get resource not found.

Comment: Draft view works but I cant view in published mode.

Comment: I can view "draft/start" but not "home/start".

Answer (score 0):

There's a miss with the 2.2.4 core package. Upgrade to the latest 2.2.4.1 patch available on NuGet which resolves the Automapper issue. Maybe your other issues are related!

Comment: But now, I can route to manager successfully but I cant see /draf/start or /home/start = resource not found. Could be a routing issue?

Comment: Sorry, I need to add a page controller to frontend.

Comment: I added a controller inherit from SinglePageController but there's an error:
`public ActionResult Index()
    {
      var model = GetModel();

      return View(model.GetView(), model);
    }`
GetView() is not a member of PageModel.

Answer (score 0):

*Installing PiranhaCMS for MVC 4*

1. Open Visual Studio 2012
2. Menu. File -> New -> Project
3. ASP.NET MVC 4 Web app.. (Installed -> Templates -> Visual C#)
4. Press Ok
5. Select Empty
6. Press Ok
7. Open Package Manager Console (PM) (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console)
8. Copy to PM "Install-Package PiranhaCMSMvc". Press Enter
9. If any promt. Write A to say yes to all overwrites of files etc.
10. Change Web.config. Add to

    ```
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor"
            publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>"
    ```
11. Run (should see a info-text about db-setup)
12. Create a db called "piranha-db"
13. Change web.config < connectionStrings ... > (according to info-text about db-setup). Ex.

    ```
      <add name="piranha" connectionString="data source=.\SQL2012;initial catalog=piranha-db;integrated security=true;multipleactiveresultsets=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />"
    ```
14. Go back to browser and click continue-link at bottom of the page
15. Done! (follow instructions to admin etc...)

Comment: If we move the connectionString into other file. How can we specify the path to the file so that piranha will read the config instead of web.config?

Comment: I do not remember. But I hope it will work if u just <connectionStrings ... point to file...> and keep the name " <add name="piranha" connectionString="d..." in the other file. Piranha will find the connectionstring.